# OOCSS - Abstracting elements inside an CSS object

Tags: css

I am learning more about OOCSS these days and I don't fully get how I can code to allow extending CSS objects.

Let's say I have this CSS object called icon-text which aligns icon with text.

HTML

```
<div class="icon-text">
    <img class="icon-text__icon"></img>
    <span class="icon-text__caption"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.icon-text {
    display: inline-block;
}
.icon-text > .icon-text__icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

It works well. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ER22t/)

But what happens if I want to wrap the `img` and/or `span`in `a` or want to use `div` instead of `span` for the caption? Using block or inline elements would definitely affect how I write CSS objects. How can I abstract elements inside an object so that it could work with different kinds of elements?

Comment: Sorry, what you show in the fiddle is _not_ what you posted in your question.

Comment: It is mostly the same as what I posted. The difference is that the fiddle has `src` attribute in the img and SCSS is compiled to CSS. I'll change SCSS to CSS in my original post to avoid confusions.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use a BEM syntax, you don't need the child selector:

```
.icon-text > .icon-text__icon
```

Just use this:

```
.icon-text__icon
```

> But what happens if I want to wrap the `img` and/or `span` in `a`

The BEM syntax solves the issues of nesting.

> or want to use `div` instead of `span` for the caption? Using block or inline elements would definitely affect how I write CSS objects. How can I abstract elements inside an object so that it could work with different kinds of elements?

OOCSS is just a way to choose CSS classes. If you plan to use alternately a `div` and a `span` for `.icon-text__caption`, then you have to set the property `display`.

Answer (score 0):

As a side-note, if you're using SASS then you can write your modules like below, which is the base i use for all of my OOCSS modules.

```
// *************************************
//
//   Overview of module and usage
//
// *************************************

// -------------------------------------
//   Variables
// -------------------------------------

$some-variable: 7em;
$some-color: #3B5998;
$some-color: #c0deed;


// -------------------------------------
//   Base
// -------------------------------------


.module {


    // -------------------------------------
    //   Elements
    // -------------------------------------


    // ----- Element description ----- // 

    &__element {}


    // -------------------------------------
    //   Variations
    // -------------------------------------


    // ----- Variation description ----- // 

    &--variation {}

}
```